# selenium doesn't enter the site

Tags: c#, selenium

I created a console application (with target: `.Net Framework 4`) and added the next references:

`Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll`

`ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll`

`WebDriver.dll`

`WebDriver.Support.dll`

```
static IWebDriver driver = null;
if (driver == null)
{
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
     driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\selenium\net40", options);
     // it opened a new window (about:blank)
}

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

but nothing is happen.

I use: `ChromeDriver 26.0.1383.0`

and my chrome browser version is: `29.0.1547.62 m`

this is the command line:

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=1866
version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Users\salon\Desktop\Application Alon\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplicati
on1\bin\Debug\chromedriver.log
[156:4144:0828/233852:ERROR:platform_thread_win.cc(127)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[5804:5712:0828/233856:ERROR:textfield.h(173)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

I have `windows 7` if it's needed..

any help appreciated!

Comment: Hm I tried your code (replaced driver location by mine) and it worked correctly, so the code is okay. The references are also correct, and the two 'NOT IMPLEMENTED' are "normal", I always get them when I start the webdriver. Can you try with a vanilla ChromeDriver? Like `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"yourdriverpath");`, no `ChromeOptions`.

Comment: I'm trying.. thank you..

Comment: no, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Hm, does it work with InternetExplorerDriver, or you cannot navigate with any drivers? You can also try to copy line by line the example [here](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2013/01/18/selenium-webdriver-using-chrome-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c/). If it still not work it's probably related to your environment and I cannot help your further =/

Comment: I will try it in the morning.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the later versions of Chrome (27+), there is a new shiny ChromeDriver:

http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Note the section within the summary on the page...

```
ChromeDriver server for win32 (v2.2.215849.dyu) supports Chrome v27-30
```

Also, you should remove the Thoughtworks & WebDriverBackedSelenium references, they are not required and you don't seem to be using them.